# Add rel="lightbox" to image (forced by javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, rel

On my website I have an image. I try to add a rel="lightbox" because I want to open the image in Lightbox when I click it. But I'm not able to change this part of the HTML code. Is there another solution to 'force' the rel with something like Javascript or jQuery?

This is the HTML code I want to add the rel="lightbox"

```
<div class="gv_panel" style="width: 240px; height: 290px;">
<img style="visibility: visible; " src="t-shirt.jpg">
</div>
```

Is there any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
$( '.gv_panel img' ).attr( 'rel', 'lightbox' );
```

And using Javascript only:

```
document.querySelector( '.gv_panel img' ).rel = 'lightbox';
```

But note that IE supports [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) only from 8+ version. So if you need to support IE7 you should use `getElementById` instead or something else.

Comment: I try the following code, but it is not working. Am I doing something wrong here?? 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
      $( '.gv_panel img' ).attr( 'rel', 'lightbox' ); 
    });
    </script>

Comment: Code looks good. Don't forget that you need to initialize your `lightbox` after this code. Because if you initialize it earlier `lightbox` script will not know about new `rel`'s

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried to move the code to a higher place on the webpage, but it's still not working.. Can you please take a look at my site? http://www.jaewhooclothing.com/collection/jae-whoo-limited-t-shirt-design/

Comment: `$` is undefined -  this is what I see in browser console. So you need to use `jQuery.` instaed of `$.`

Comment: Good idea to use the console, I tried to change the $ in jQuery, but now the console is telling me: "jQuery is not defined"

Comment: This is because your code is before jQuery initialization `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.jaewhooclothing.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>` it should be after  jquery but before lightbox.

Comment: I tried to move the jQuery code between the jQuery initialization and lightbox, but it still gives the same result: http://www.jaewhooclothing.com/collection/jae-whoo-limited-t-shirt-design/

Comment: Try also after adding rel attr init lightbox `$( '.gv_panel img' ).lightbox();`

Comment: This gives me the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lightbox'

Comment: IDK what lightbox exactly you are using. You need to google your's lightbox api better

Comment: I allready use Lightbox on other pages from the website. But it's not a problem to use another like Colorbox or Thickbox. But I still need to add an attribute to the img element, is that right?